# Access properties of objects in an array- Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, struct, tableview

I create a `struct` in a `ViewController` file which has the properties `url`, `img`, and `name`. Here is that code:

```
struct Article {

var url: URL
var img: URL
var title: String

    init(url: URL, img: URL, title: String) {
        self.url = url
        self.img = img
        self.title = title
    }
}
```

When the user presses a button, I create an instance of the struct, assign data to the properties, and put it in an array called `bookmarks`. Then in a `TableView` file, I want to loop through `bookmarks` and grab each struct's `url`, `img`, and `name` so I can assign them to labels on each cell.

The trouble I am having is I do not know how to access each `struct`'s properties inside `bookmarks`.

If anyone could help me accomplish this, that would be amazing. Any help will be appreciated! Thanks so much in advance. Cheers, Theo

Comment: In `celForRow(at;)` you use the `indexPath.row` to get an `Article` out of the array and then access the properties using `.url` as usual. Can you show your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the struct's properties with a dot `.` followed by the property name.

Here is an example:

```
let article = Article(url: URL(string: ""), img: URL(string: ""), title: "hello")
let theTitle = article.title // equal to "hello"
```

In your case, you want to grab the information for a table view. Assuming you have an array of `Article` named `bookmarks`, simply index into this array in the table view's `cellForRowAt indexPath` data source method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourIdentifierHere")
    let article = bookmarks[indexPath.row]
    let title = article.title
    cell.titleLabel.text = title
    return cell
}
```

This data source method is called on your behalf, so it "loops" through the data array automatically.

Comment: thanks so much, nathan! i implemented your answer and i have two problems: first, when I put `let title = article.title` in I get an error (Value of 'Any' has no member 'title') and second, when i try attaching a label from the storyboard it says i cant attach a label to repeating content. would you reccomend creating the label programatically?

Comment: How is your `bookmarks` array defined? It should look something like this `var bookmarks: [Article] = []` for the compiler to know that objects of `Article` type are stored there. It is important in swift, as it is a strongly typed language. As to the label, `titleLabel` is a standard label provided by the SDK. If you have a custom design of your cell, you'd need to create a subclass of `UITableViewCell` to assign it's outlets.

Comment: @Losiowaty i made a typo there! great call. thanks a ton. do you have any idea how to solve the label problem though...?

Comment: As I said, if you have a custom design, you will have to create a subclass of `UITableViewCell` - explaining all this would be too long for a comment, and out of scope for this question, but there are many tutorials out there (like this : https://peterwitham.com/swift-archives/intermediate/creating-and-using-ios-prototype-cells-with-swift/ ). But if all you want to display is a line of text and an image, you can use standard views on `UITableViewCell` provided by the SDK - you can read more in the docs -
 http://apple.co/2pnNe0j .